# firt time using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi everyone I have a problem when using ajax. when I submit the form with "Script"alert(aaaa)"script" in textarea my form is wrong, and I don't now how to validation with ajax to avoid my problem. thank for help. `

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sub").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var comment =$("#com").val();
        if ($.trim(comment) == "") {
            alert("u must fill here");
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
           type: 'json',
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
               "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
           },
           url: 'http://ivsexpress.net/index.php?controller=postdetail&method=create&post_id=<?php echo $_GET['post_id']; ?>',
           data: {
               comment: comment
           },
           success: function(data){
                var data = JSON.parse(data);  
                $("#form")[0].reset();
                $("#Comment_ajax").prepend($("<div></div>").html(
                 '<h4 style="font-size:15px;color:#9f224e">'+ data.full_name +'</h4>'+
                 '<h6 style="font-style:italic">'+ 'vào lúc: '+ data.created_date+'</h6>'+
                 '<p style="font-size:13px;text-align:justify;word-break:break-word;">'+ data.content +'</p>'+'<br>'
                ));
           },
           error: function(data, status, jqxhr){
               console.log(status);
           }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

`

Comment: Please put a bit more effort into explaining whats wrong, please? :) Looks like your new to stack.

Comment: what do you mean by **my form is wrong**?

Comment: oh sory , my browser show alert "aaaaaa" and my comment not insert into my database. yeah this is my firt time using ajax and jquery :'(.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding this correctly, you need to escape the `data.content` part as you are concatenating string to produce html elements(which is a bad practice). Anyways, you can escape it by using

```
var escaped_full_name = $('<p>').append(data.full_name).html();
var escaped_content = $('<p>').append(data.content).html();
var escaped_created_date = $('<p>').append(data.created_date).html();
```

and using it as

```
$("#Comment_ajax").prepend($("<div></div>").html(
                 '<h4 style="font-size:15px;color:#9f224e">'+ escaped_full_name +'</h4>'+
                 '<h6 style="font-style:italic">'+ 'vào lúc: '+ escaped_created_date+'</h6>'+
                 '<p style="font-size:13px;text-align:justify;word-break:break-word;">'+ escaped_content +'</p>'+'<br>'
                ));
```

Still, i highly recommend not using string concatenation for creating html elements